# How to populate view with database information after AJAX request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

Hi there once again SO community. I've been developing a site and so far it's going pretty well. But today after a long day searching for a solution I can't understand nor find what the right path is...

I want to click on a button and a profile page where you can edit the fields appear. I can redirect to the page I want but I don't know how to send the user data so I can populate the fields.

Here is my button code on my view

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="border-color: black" id="dados_{{ $user->username }}"> Alterar Dados Pessoais

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>

</button>
```

Here is the button AJAX request handler

```
if((this.id).indexOf("dados") != -1){

    var content = this.id.replace("dados_", "");

    $.get('callPermissions', {usernameSend:content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),}, function(data){

    window.location.replace('settings');

});
```

And here is my callPermission Controller

```
public function callPermissions(Request $request)
{

  if($request->ajax()){

    $usernames = Input::get('usernameSend');

    if(isset($usernames)){

      $user = User::Where('username', '=', $usernames)->first();

      $returnHTML =  view('userOptions.settings')->render();

      return view('userOptions.settings');

    }else{

      Log::warning("Username não existe na base de dados.");

    }

  }

}
```

and here my Settings Controller

```
public function settings(Request $request)
{

    return view('userOptions.settings');

}
```

And here is the route

```
Route::get('/callPermissions', 'SidebarController@callPermissions');
```

I know the controller is wrong and from what I've read I should verify if the AJAX is successful and if it is handle i on the AJAX request. But from what I've understand I'm not using the Controller at all (even though it goes there). How should I send the user information (in this case the username, then I can get everything from the database) and then send it to the view? I've been searching and trying out stuff that doesn't work...since the **return view("your_view")** on the Controller doesn't work.

Sorry if I've been confusing and if you need additional information feel free to ask!

Thanks for your help!!

**Edit**: If I return this on the controller

```
return view('userOptions.settings', compact('user'));
```

and do a replace with the Ajax request as show above and add this to the settings view

```
<p> {{ $user->name }} </p>
```

I get the following error **Undefined variable: user (View: C:\wamp64\www\siteXL\ideiasxl\resources\views\userOptions\settings.blade.php)**

Is there anyway to send the parameters with a **compact** alike or I need to send it through the link? Was avoiding to show the username on the url.

**Edit2:** For further clarification, this works as intended

```
<button onclick="window.location='{{url('/settings/' . $user->username)}}'" type="button" id="dadosPessoais" class="btn btn-default">Alterar Dados Pessoais

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></i>

</button>
```

but I was trying not to send id's and usernames through the URL.

If this is not achievable it's ok, but if there's a way I can't find it, that's why I'm asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to add a parameter in the Route and receive the data in the controller function. I'd do something like this:

Route:

```
Route::get('/callPermissions/{user}', 'SidebarController@callPermissions');
```

Controller:

```
public function callPermissions(Request $request, $user)
{
//get data related to $user
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.get('callPermissions/'+userIdVariable, {usernameSend:content, '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),}, function(data){

    window.location.replace('settings');

});
```

This would send the user id through the route.

To get the user id with JavaScript, you can make a hidden field in the Blade file and set the user id as the value. For example, if you using Form helper:

```
{{ Form::hidden('user_id', $user->id, array('id' => 'js-user-id')) }}
```

And then, in the JavaScript, you can get the value using something like this:

```
var userIdVariable = $('#js-user-id')->val();
```

Comment: How would you send the user id (for example) to the settings page on the Ajax call? I know how to do that through the controller but since I'm using AJAX requests the return **view('path.to.settings', compact('user')** -- for example -- doesn't work! I wanted to send to the settings view the user id.

I'll update the main post

Thanks for the answer though

Comment: One way to do this is to use a hidden field in the form and set the value as user->id. Then, you can get the value of the field using jQuery for example. I'll edit the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense! Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you!